# Proving that a minimum example exists if any example exists in nat

Tags: coq, natural-numbers

I'm trying to prove that if a function from nat -> bool is true for any natural number, then there exists a minimum natural number which the function is true for.

I've been trying to find a good min_prop function to find this minimum true value, but I've had trouble proving the result of the min_prop function is actually the minimum true value.

I've written one version of this min_prop function, which only checks the first n values.

```
Fixpoint min_pb (pb : nat -> bool) (max : nat) :=
  match max with
  | O => if pb O then Some O else None
  | S max' =>
    let r := min_pb pb max' in
    match r with
    | None => if pb max then Some max else None
    | Some n => Some n
    end
  end.
```

Is there a better approach than using a minimum function, or a better minimum function, or easy proof of the one I've already written?

Comment: What if you have `min_pb` have a return type that's something like `{forall n, n < max -> pb n = false} + {exists n : nat, (n < max) /\ (pb n = true)}`? Maybe easier said than done, but I think that'd help with the main proof if you can.

Comment: Good idea. I'll try something like that.

Comment: I'm going to try using sub to count up from 0 to max with this: 
``` Fixpoint min_pb_rev (pb : nat -> bool) (max : nat) (cs : nat) :=
  match cs with
  | O => if pb max then Some max else None
  | S cs' => if pb (sub max (S cs')) then Some (sub max (S cs')) else min_pb_rev pb max cs'
  end.`

Comment: I thought about it and I came up with proving: 
forall (pb : nat -> bool) (n : nat), (forall (u : nat), le u n -> pb u = false) 
                  \/ (exists (min : nat), pb min = true /\ (forall (u : nat), lt u min -> pb u = false)), which works nicely with induction on n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use MathComp, `ssrnat` provides [`ex_minn`](https://math-comp.github.io/htmldoc/mathcomp.ssreflect.ssrnat.html#ex_minn),  which I think gives you exactly what you are trying to prove (e.g., see [`ExMinnSpec`](https://math-comp.github.io/htmldoc/mathcomp.ssreflect.ssrnat.html#ExMinnSpec)).

Comment: There are also similar things [in the standard library](https://coq.inria.fr/doc/V8.17.1/stdlib/Coq.Logic.ConstructiveEpsilon.html).

Answer (score 2):

Here's the start of a cute solution:

```
Fixpoint minimise (f : nat -> bool) (max : nat) : nat :=
  if f 0 then 0 else
  match max with
  | 0 => 0
  | S max' => minimise (fun n => f (S n)) max'
  end.

Theorem minimise_correct : forall (max : nat) (f : nat -> bool),
    f max = true -> f (minimise f max) = true /\ (forall n, n < minimise f max -> f n = false).
Proof.
  induction max.
```

Comment: Looks like a good approach. I used induction to prove, 

Lemma min_prop : forall (pb : nat -> bool) (n : nat), (forall (u : nat), le u n -> pb u = false) \/ (exists (min : nat), pb min = true /\ (forall (u : nat), lt u min -> pb u = false)).